# Redirecting to some sites in webview with in the app

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an android app in Google Playstore.

The app opens some third party site(s) with in a web view inside the app.

Is there any problem to publish such an app in Google Playstore?
or is there any chance to get my Google-developer account banned?

Comment: no, there is no any such restriction. you can publish your app.

Comment: unless you have explicit permission from the third party sites you trying to open in your app, you can have problem. You need permission and citations to use content of anyones' web content in your app.